# How to set data from ViewController to UITableView custom Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, custom-cell

I have been trying to pass data from Viewcontroller to UITableView custom cell using custom delegate.There are answers for passing data from Custom cell to ViewController but none for the viceversa .Can anyone suggest me with some idea or sample code.

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: You cant pass directly. But you can do by using model class. Model class contains the data what you are going to pass. In `viewcontroller` you can save the data to Model. And in customcell class you can retrive.

Comment: why downvote the question?

Comment: what do u mean by model class.Are you refering to sharedclass? @user3774439

Comment: Yeah. You can use that

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you mean, but you can set the data in `function tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

**For example:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ViewController.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.data = data 
        return cell

    }
```